# Visual studio code C++(auto keyword error but the code compiler and shows the correct output)

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

Code when I was testing vectors:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> a;
    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
        a.push_back(i);
    }
    for(auto i = a.begin();i!=a.end();++i){
            cout<<*i<<" ";
        }
}
```

Now this shows the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWOxG.png)

But the code compiles correctly
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aetzJ.png)

I am not sure what's wrong with the auto keyword.

Comment: Don't post link to images with error, paste the compiler errors directly.

Comment: That is not a compiler error.  That is an error that your third-party tool is stating.  That third-party tool is not a C++ compiler.  Actual C++ compiler errors come with error numbers or an error identifier.

Comment: funny coincidende that the message points to column 11 in line 11 and does not recognize a C++11 feature (one more and the question would have 11 views :/)

Comment: Either you have an IDE that is highlighting an error in the edit window for valid code, or you have confused your IDE so it is running a previously compiled executable.    If you are compiling for C++11 and later, the problem is probably the first of these (at a guess because the syntax highlighting is configured for pre-2011 C++).   If you are compiling for C++ before 2011, the problem is probably the second.

Comment: "this shows..." you need to understand that "this" is completely unrelated to compiling your code, but a feature of your IDE that is supposed to help with errors before you actually compile. Such tools cannot be perfect, but here the issue is just that you have to configure it for C++11

Comment: Apparently code lint is setup to use old version of C++. Please specify which plugin provides code highlighting on your machine. Check plugin settings.

Comment: I am very thankful that you guys pointed out the error. It is working now that I changed the C_Cpp>Default: Cpp Standard settings to c++17.